# Trouble downloading files using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am attempting to extract data from a table that shows a list of active bids from [this site](https://purchasing.alabama.gov/active-statewide-contracts/). I am a Scrapy newbie, and bit stuck as to why I get no downloaded files. I am able to output the file urls, but still unable to get scrapy to download the files from the listed urls. I am unable to figure out what I am missing or need to change. Any help towards this end will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

I have the following code so far:

Here is my **spider**:

```
from government.items import GovernmentItem
import scrapy, urllib.parse
import scrapy
from government.items import GovernmentItem


class AlabamaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alabama'
    allowed_domains = ['purchasing.alabama.gov']

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://purchasing.alabama.gov/active-statewide-contracts/'

        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    
    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm"]//tbody//tr'):

            yield {
                'Description': row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[@class="col-sm-5"])').extract_first(),
                'Bid File': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1"]/a//@href').extract_first(),
                'Begin Date': row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[@class="col-sm-1"][2])').extract_first(),
                'End Date': row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[@class="col-sm-1"][3])').extract_first(),
                'Buyer Name': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-3"]/a//text()').extract_first(),
                'Vendor Websites': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1"]/label/text()').extract_first(),
            }
   
    def parse_item(self, response):
        file_url = response.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1"]/a//@href').get()
        #file_url = response.urljoin(file_url)
        item = GovernmentItem()
        item['file_urls'] = [file_url]
        yield item
```

Here is **items.py**:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import scrapy
    
class GovernmentItem(Item):
    file_urls = Field()
    files = Field()
```

Here is my **settings.py**:

```
BOT_NAME = 'government'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['government.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'government.spiders'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure item pipelines
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'government.pipelines.GovernmentPipeline': 1,
    'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1,
   }

FILES_STORE = '/home/ken/Desktop/Projects/scrapy/government'
FILES_URL_FIELD = 'field_urls'
FILES_RESULT_FIELD = 'files'
MEDIA_ALLOW_REDIRECTS = True
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. You never call "parse_item" function
2. `file_url = response.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1"]/a//@href').get()` will return none. you forgot to add '//' at the beggining.
3. You need to download each file separately. So get the download links with getall() and then handle them one by one.

The corrected code:

```
    def parse_all_items(self, response):
        all_urls = response.xpath('//td[@class="col-sm-1"]/a//@href').getall()
        base_url = 'https://purchasing.alabama.gov'
        for url in all_urls:
            item = GovernmentItem()
            item['file_urls'] = [base_url + url]
            yield item
```

It will download all the files.
Just make sure that you remember to call that function.

**Alternative solution:** Use the parse function you already have:

```
def parse(self, response):
    base_url = 'https://purchasing.alabama.gov'
    for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm"]//tbody//tr'):
        url = row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1"]/a//@href').extract_first()
        yield {
            'Description': row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[@class="col-sm-5"])').extract_first(),
            'Bid File': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1"]/a//@href').extract_first(),
            'Begin Date': row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[@class="col-sm-1"][2])').extract_first(),
            'End Date': row.xpath('normalize-space(./td[@class="col-sm-1"][3])').extract_first(),
            'Buyer Name': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-3"]/a//text()').extract_first(),
            'Vendor Websites': row.xpath('td[@class="col-sm-1"]/label/text()').extract_first(),
        }
        if url:
            item = GovernmentItem()
            item['file_urls'] = [base_url + url]
            yield item
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!! I have updated my solution. I run the crawler using `scrapy crawl alabama` and I still don't have any files downloaded. I am lost by you mean by to make sure to `parse_all_items` function and would like to seek further clarification. Thanks again!

Comment: @KenRuto add `yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_all_items)`

Comment: thanks for your response. I am still a bit tangled with where to call this function

Comment: @KenRuto I added another solution, just copy it.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and solution it worked great! Thanks again @user16429780

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1}
FILES_STORE = '/path/to/valid/dir'
```

to settings.py?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry I forgot to add this to my post.

Comment: I've added the settings.py to my post.

Comment: Asking questions back to the OP can also be clarified in the comments to the original post. This does not justify as an answer.